# PagedList Asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pagedlist

I  use pagedlist in my application but I  get an error in the view saying it connot convert list to Ipagedlist

here is my code:

```
 .Where(x => x.ID == ID)
                 .Where(x => x.IsDeleted == IncludeDeleted).ToList()
                 .ToPagedList(1,3);
```

in my controller action method I have this:

```
 IPagedList<CoreModels.Product> list = _Productservice.GetList(ID);
        model.Options = Mapper.Map<List<MyModels.Product.ProductEditModel>>(list.OrderBy(x => x.pos));
```

in the view:

```
@model App.Models.ElementOption.ProductEditListModel
 @using PagedList.Mvc;
    @using PagedList;
    <link href="~/Content/PagedList.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

  @Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList)Model.Options, page => Url.Action("Details", "Product", new { ID = Model.ID }))
```

Comment: What is your specific question?

Comment: I want to be able to display pages number

Comment: And you are using the X.PagedList from Troy Goode et al.?

Comment: yes exactly it works fine if I remove this from the view  @Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList)Model.Options, page => Url.Action("Details", "Product", new I can display now only 3 items but

Comment: but I  want to display pages number

Comment: @Jack.D Model.Options needs to be of type IPagedList. So after using AutoMapper, you need to create IPagedList<>, not before using AutoMapper

Comment: @Jack.D Is the first code snippet from your `GetList()` method?

Comment: Options is already an  IPagedList.

Comment: @Jack.D No it's not anymore because you're asking AutoMapper to map it to a `List<....ProductEditModel>`

Comment: sorry my bad I just change that but still the same error

Comment: So, the question again is, how have you defined the `Options` property on your model class (`ProductEditListModel`)?

Comment: public IPagedList<App.Models.Product.ProductEditModel> Options { get; set; }

Comment: Is the first code snippet (with the `.Where()` calls) from your `GetList()` method? In that case, I would re-architect that. Your core should not know about paged lists because that is a UI concern. The core should just return `IList<>` instances. After you refactor that, wait until the last moment (i.e. after mapping `CoreModels.Product` to `ProductEditModel`) to convert to an IPagedList. I think this will simplify the debugging of this problem and result in cleaner separation of concerns.

Comment: I 'll try that thank you

Comment: still facing the same problem at this line     @Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList)Model.Options, page => Url.Action("Details", "Product", new { ID= Model.ID }))

Comment: Maybe at this point it's best to update your code snippets.

Comment: Also, have you tried NOT casting to IPagedList and just using `@Html.PagedListPage(Model.Options, ...)`?

Comment: yes it didn't work either ..